# How to seach in C# sql database by LIKE

Tags: c#, sql-server, search

I have a table and I want to search in the table.

```
SELECT tbPhonebook.*
FROM tbPhonebook    
WHERE Fname LIKE @fanem
```

in `tbPhonebookTableAdaptor`, and use this :

```
private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     tbPhonebookTableAdapter.search(this.test4Dataset.tbPhonebook, textBox1.Text);
}
```

and it works fine, but when somebody searches for a word, all words which contain that search expression will be shown.

For example there are these names in the database:

```
ali , alireza , soheil , soheilyou , ....
```

In current search if user searches for `ali` the program just will show him `ali` while `alireza` also contains the `ali` search criteria!

In php I could use this :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbPhonebook    
WHERE Fname LIKE "%$fanem%"
```

but I don't know syntax in C#

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure what you're asking, but in C# you can use `String.Contains()` method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Security concerns aside, you could use a concatenated string for your query like:

```
"SELECT tbPhonebook.* FROM tbPhonebook WHERE Fname LIKE '%"+textBox1.Text+"%'"
```

An example for a more secure way to do this to avoid SQL injections you can find here: [SQL Parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

Comment: I found it and I wanted to write answer and saw you did it ;) tnx anway

Comment: You would make me unbelievably happy if you'd accept the answer! :-)

Comment: sure my friend ;) and you can score question

Comment: Please use sql parameters to avoid sql injection attacks

Comment: So please don't submit answers with known security problems. Show the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should learn c# syntax to be a better c# developer.

i use this SQL command and it works for me. it searches my DB on textchang event on any character inputted on the textbox.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Studentreg WHERE RegNo like '%" + txtquick.Text + "%' or StudentName LIKE '%" + txtquick.Text + "%'";
```

Comment: Beware of little Bobby Tables!